# How to take a picture with native camera, crop it to be squared and then upload it to Parse.com as ParseFile?

Tags: android, parse-platform, upload, camera, android-camera-intent

How do I take a picture with the native phone camera and then crop it to be squared , and upload it like that to Parse.com as a ParseFile.
The name of the Table in parse is "Gallery" and the name of the column where it has to be saved is "photo".
Can anyone please help me.

P.S. I don't need to save the picture to the phone at all, only upload it to parse and then discard it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi drilonreqica, please [edit] your question to include any specifics that you may have already tried, and any specific errors you are facing; the SO community is happy to _help_, but will not write your code for you. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @MattClark ok Mark I will post what I have tried , and then somebody may be able to help me..

Comment: Why.... Why does _everybody_ call me Mark :/

Comment: @MattClark haha sorry autocorrect mistake :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks guy but after looking for some time I found the solution.
This is it if anyone needs it in the future.
This is how you take a picture , and upload it to Parse.com without saving it to the device.

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_picture);

            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
(mFile));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            byte[] image_byte_array;
                  ParseObject post_object = new ParseObject("Gallery");
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                image_byte_array = stream.toByteArray();
                ParseFile picture_file = new ParseFile("Picture.jpg", image_byte_array);
                picture_file.saveInBackground();
                post_object.put("photo", picture_file);
                post_object.saveInBackground();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
Bitmap bmp = image;
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bmp2);
img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

I think ive done it like this before... I had to use parse for a project one time and was messing around with the bitmaps. Hopefully this helps